# number of maximizers

Tags: analysis, optimization

Suppose f(x) is continuous in x∈X, where X is compact. Let T(x):=argmaxf(x) be the set of maximum of f(x), where the maxf(x) is bounded. Then under what condition the set T(x) cannot contain infinitely many distinct points? Here x' and x'' are said to be distinct if there is no path in T(x) connecting x' and x''. I know that the bounded variation is sufficient (or piecewise monotone), but can we have even more general conditions? Thank you!

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. Are you asking when does $T(x)$ have finitely many components?

Comment: quite close. If we define each "component" in a way that any two points within a component can be connected by some path. For example, if x*∈T(x), and any small neighborhood of x* also in T(x), then x* and its small neighborhood should belong to the same component. Thank you!